# Is there a way to use struct values inside of an enum?

Tags: c++, struct, enums

In my program I want to represent some musical note durations symbolically by using an `enum class`. The numeric values represented by the symbolic enum names are doubles, however enums work only with ints so I had the idea to use a fixed point representation for the values and then do a division when the enum is returned from a getter method somewhere else in the program. For this I used a struct however I am unable to use values from a struct within an enum due to the struct values not being literals. The compiler complains that "expression must have a constant value".

```cpp
const double fp_multiplier = 10000.00; //utility const for fixed point conversion

// fixed point representations of note values
struct {
  const int whole = (int)(1.0*fp_multiplier);
  const int half = (int)(0.5*fp_multiplier);
  const int eigth = (int)(0.125*fp_multiplier);
  const int sixteenth = (int)(0.0625*fp_multiplier);
  const int dotted_eigth = (int)((eigth + 0.5*eigth)*fp_multiplier); 
  const int dotted_sixteenth = (int)((sixteenth + 0.5*sixteenth)*fp_multiplier);
} NoteValues;


enum class NoteValue {
  whole = NoteValues.whole, //not allowed
  half = NoteValues.half,
  eigth = NoteValues.eigth,
  sixteenth = NoteValues.sixteenth,
  dotted_eigth = NoteValues.dotted_eigth,
  dotted_sixteenth = NoteValues.dotted_sixteenth,
};
```

As I understand this is not allowed as `NoteValues.whole` is not an instance of the struct? It's not a literal or constant value (constant being different and unrelated to the `const` keyword in this case). How can I assign the enum values to the values in the struct in a way which satisfies the compiler or is there an alternative better way to achieve this? I specifically want to be able to have an enum for notevalues.

Comment: `NoteValues` is an instance of a class. But class members cannot be used as compile-time constant values.

Comment: `struct NoteValues { static const int whole = (int)(1.0*fp_multiplier);` and then `whole = NoteValues::whole,`

Comment: @MarekR `NoteValues` is not a type name, and is `const` enough (or should it be `constexpr`)?

Comment: You're probably looking for `static constexpr`.  You'll probably find using an exact power of two for `fp_multiplier` helps your accuracy, as that will result in integer values.

Comment: But why a struct in the first place? Just write the expressions directly in the `enum`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it should be constexpr. Right side of `const` is evaluated runtime. Though the compiler optimizes it away, this happens at a later stage in the pipeline.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/c689nd7qK

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried that initially but I can't write something like `enum class NoteValue {eigth = (int)(0.125*fp_multiplier), dotted_eigth = (int)(eigth+0.5*eigth) , }` which is why I tried using the struct.

Comment: It works for me if I replace `const` on `fp_multiplier` with `constexpr`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nzcM9xer5 Adding an extra struct in the middle shouldn't help in such situations.

Comment: FWIW whatever you end up doing, everything is going to be simpler if you store the reciprocal of the duration (eg. `sixteenth = 16`)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat interesting, if I get rid of the struct, turn `NoteValues` into a namespace with static members and add `constexpr` to `fp_multiplier` I still get "enumerator value for 'dotted_sixteenth' is not an integer constant". Which compiler and C++ version are you using?

Comment: You don't even need the namespace, you can write the expression directly in the enum. In my link you can see it working in Clang 17. It also works in GCC 13 and the latest MSVC, which you can test on the same site. What compiler are you testing it on?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat avr g++, the target platform is an arduino.

Comment: I reproduced it. You need to drop `*fp_multiplier` from the two last constants. You end up applying the multiplier twice, giving you wrong values, and AVR GCC is unhappy because you overflow the tiny 2-byte `int`s.

Comment: Nice, good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the object `NoteValues` into a type, make the members static, and use the class access syntax.
You also need to make `fp_multiplier` into a `constexpr`.

```
constexpr double fp_multiplier = 10000.00;

struct NoteValues{
  static const int whole = (int)(1.0*fp_multiplier);
  static const int half = (int)(0.5*fp_multiplier);
  static const int eigth = (int)(0.125*fp_multiplier);
  static const int sixteenth = (int)(0.0625*fp_multiplier);
  static const int dotted_eigth = (int)((eigth + 0.5*eigth)*fp_multiplier); 
  static const int dotted_sixteenth = (int)((sixteenth + 0.5*sixteenth)*fp_multiplier);
};


enum class NoteValue {
  whole = NoteValues::whole, // allowed
  half = NoteValues::half,
  eigth = NoteValues::eigth,
  sixteenth = NoteValues::sixteenth,
  dotted_eigth = NoteValues::dotted_eigth,
  dotted_sixteenth = NoteValues::dotted_sixteenth,
};
```

It might also be an option to turn `NoteValues` into a namespace, but it's also not clear what the point of duplicating the information is.
Why not just

```
enum class NoteValues{
  whole = (int)(1.0*fp_multiplier),
  half = (int)(0.5*fp_multiplier),
  eigth = (int)(0.125*fp_multiplier),
  sixteenth = (int)(0.0625*fp_multiplier),
  dotted_eigth = (int)((eigth + 0.5*eigth)*fp_multiplier), 
  dotted_sixteenth = (int)((sixteenth + 0.5*sixteenth)*fp_multiplier)
};
```

Comment: Could make it a namespace at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a summary of my comments as an answer.

1. You just need to make `fp_multiplier` `constexpr`, then you can place the expressions directly in the enum definition. Having a struct in the middle doesn't do anything useful.
2. You have a typo in the last two expressions, you apply the multiplier twice. This causes a compilation error on your AVR GCC, because if overflows the tiny 2-byte `int`s.

Here's the fixed code:

```
constexpr double fp_multiplier = 10000.00;

enum class NoteValue
{
    whole = (int)(1.0*fp_multiplier),
    half = (int)(0.5*fp_multiplier),
    eigth = (int)(0.125*fp_multiplier),
    sixteenth = (int)(0.0625*fp_multiplier),
    dotted_eigth = (int)(eigth + 0.5*eigth),
    dotted_sixteenth = (int)(sixteenth + 0.5*sixteenth),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is other way to fix this what is closer to your original code:

```cpp
constexpr double fp_multiplier = 10000.00;

constexpr struct {
  const int whole = (int)(1.0*fp_multiplier);
  const int half = (int)(0.5*fp_multiplier);
  const int eigth = (int)(0.125*fp_multiplier);
  const int sixteenth = (int)(0.0625*fp_multiplier);
  const int dotted_eigth = (int)((eigth + 0.5*eigth)*fp_multiplier); 
  const int dotted_sixteenth = (int)((sixteenth + 0.5*sixteenth)*fp_multiplier);
} NoteValues;


enum class NoteValue {
  whole = NoteValues.whole,
  half = NoteValues.half,
  eigth = NoteValues.eigth,
  sixteenth = NoteValues.sixteenth,
  dotted_eigth = NoteValues.dotted_eigth,
  dotted_sixteenth = NoteValues.dotted_sixteenth,
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eq3b7PhG8

In your original code `NoteValues` was a variable. Now it is a const expression, so values are known at compile time and can be used to define value of enumeration items.